# How to find which version of Oracle is installed on a Linux server (In terminal)

Tags: linux, oracle, rhel

I am in terminal in Redhat 5.5 and I need to find out which version of Oracle is installed. I am pretty new at Linux, but I have searched Google for a while and I can't find what I need. I have to locate which version is installed via terminal. I found the Oracle files, but I can't seem to find the version.

Comment: Can you connect to the oracle DB? if so, just run `select * from v$version;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the user running the Oracle Database one can also try `$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch/opatch lsinventory` which shows the exact version and patches installed.

For example this is a quick oneliner which should only return the version number:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch/opatch lsinventory | awk '/^Oracle Database/ {print $NF}'
```

Comment: It is remarkable hard to find out the actual patch level. lsinventory is the best approach. You might want to add -bugs_fixed. On the PSU level you can use `select comments, version, bundle_series from sys.registry$history where bundle_series = 'PSU' order by action_time;`

Answer (score 16):

Enter in sqlplus (you'll see the version number)

```
# su - oracle

oracle# sqlplus
```

OR

```
echo $ORAHOME
```

Will give you the path where Oracle installed and path will include version number.

OR

Connect to Oracle DB and run

```
select * from v$version where banner like 'oracle%';
```

Comment: First off thanks for your reply. I got into the Oracle file, and ran ls. The list of files are 'bea emkey.ora glibc-devel-2.5-49.i386.rpm oradiag_oracle' does one of those contain the Oracle version?

Comment: It's enough to login to SQL*Plus and version is printed to the output.

Comment: idk of previous versions, but in 11g the condition would be: "where banner like 'Oracle%' since the result is: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 6):

Login as sys user in sql*plus. Then do this query:

```
select * from v$version;
```

or

```
select * from product_component_version;
```

Answer (score 3):

As A.B.Cada pointed out, you can query the database itself with sqlplus for the db version.  That is the easiest way to findout what is the version of the db that is actively running.  If there is more than one you will have to set the oracle_sid appropriately and run the query against each instance.

You can view /etc/oratab file to see what instance and what db home is used per instance.  Its possible to have multiple version of oracle installed per server as well as multiple instances.  The /etc/oratab file will list all instances and db home.  From with the oracle db home you can run "opatch lsinventory" to find out what exaction version of the db is installed as well as any patches applied to that db installation.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in about 1 minute by just reading the startup script (in my case */etc/init.d/oracle-xe*):

> less /etc/init.d/oracle-xe

At almost the beginning of the file I found:

> ORACLE_HOME=**[PATH_TO_INSTALLATION_INCLUDING_VERSION_NUMBER]**

This was the quickest solution for me because I knew where the script was located, and that it is used for starting/restarting the server.

Of course, this relies on that the version number actually corresponds to the actual server version, which it should for a correctly installed instance.

Answer (score 0):

A bit manual searching but its an alternative way...
Find the Oracle home or where the installation files for Oracle is installed on your linux server.

```
cd / <-- Goto root directory
find . -print| grep -i dbm*.sql
```

Result varies on how you installed Oracle but mine displays this

```
/db/oracle
```

Goto the folder

```
less /db/oracle/db1/sqlplus/doc/README.htm
```

scroll down and you should see something like this

SQL*Plus Release Notes - **Release 11.2.0.2**

Answer (score -1):

you can also check by

```
ps -ef |grep -i ora
```